# Why can't I create IBActions from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a storyboard view controller that inherits from a UINavigationController but for some reason can not create IBActions, only IBOutlets. I have changed the class of the view controller to fit my class that I'm trying to create the IBAction in. Why is this happening? Any help would be much appreciated.
I have attached an image of the problem here: [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zocAO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily make IBAction's in the header file.

```
//This is your header file
@interface AppMain{
   //Outlets and others here   
}

//Actions, Voids, Properties and others here.
```

Where you put the actions -

```
-(IBAction)[Name of action];
```

In the storyboard in the linker you can link up your Action to the button.

Comment: Do you HAVE to link it up? You could just take a moment to type it out.

Comment: To use it in the main do -(IBAction)[Name of Action] {  (code)   }